# How to make line through text animation in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation

I'm developing a todo app. and in that app when a task is done, then the `lineThrough` field will enable.
but it is very boring cos there is no effect on it. so I want to make the line through effect as animation.
how do I do that

**here is an example.**

[image]

**here is my code**

```
 Text.rich(
    TextSpan(text: task.title),
    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
    style: TextStyle(
        fontFamily: 'Helvatica_lite',
        decoration: task.isDone == true
            ? TextDecoration.lineThrough
            : TextDecoration.none,
        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
        fontSize: 15,
        color: task.isDone == true ? Colors.grey : Colors.black),
  );
```

how do I make the line through animation in flutter???

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this with the line through effect. This video explains the process quite well: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ItlNXTVB6bw

Answer (score 0):

A couple weeks ago, I published a package of mine that does just that.

https://pub.dev/packages/animated_line_through

To use it just add this package to your app and then wrap your `Text` widget with `AnimatedLineThrough` widget.

There is a more info in readme.

That's still got some issues with `TextField`, but it's already showing well with the `Text` (also with Rich).